Firestore security rule exists() works inline rule but not in a function
I'm experiencing an issue with Firestore security rules. I have two versions of a rule that checks if a document exists, but only one of them works.
The inline version works fine:
match /orgs/{org} {
  allow get: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/rbac/$(org)/users/$(request.auth.uid));
}

However, when I move the same logic into a function and end up with the following security rules:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  function isUser(uid) {
    return request.auth.uid == uid;
  }
  
  function isOrgAdmin(org) {
    return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/rbac/$(org)/admins/$(request.auth.uid));
  }

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{uid} {
      allow get: if isUser(uid);
    }

    match /orgs/{org} {
      allow get: if isOrgAdmin(org);
    }
  }
}


The reads from my Angular fireAngular fail:
Error getting document: orgs/18237018238blahblahblah FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrong and why the function-based approach is not working?

Please edit the question to show the overall structure of the entire set of rules, not just the bits you're showing now.  The organization of those bits might matter a lot.

Also, if you are testing this in the console or using a test framework, please show whatever error you're seeing.  Just saying "it doesn't work" isn't really enough - we need to know how you are debugging this, and be able to reproduce the problem ourselves using the information you provide.

"it doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. So please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Hi @DougStevenson thank you for your comment. After you mentioned "The organization of those bits might matter a lot" I moved the function around and the rules grant read access when the user should get them, however I cannot explain why.

@AlexMamo thank you, I have updated the question and provided an answer, although I am not sure why the issue seems fixed.

Refactoring the security rules and moving around the function declaration fixes the problem (my angular client is granted the read permission).
The change is to declare the function right after this line:
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

Working security rules:
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

  function isUser(uid) {
    return request.auth.uid == uid;
  }
  
  function isOrgAdmin(org) {
    return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/rbac/$(org)/admins/$(request.auth.uid));
  }


    match /users/{uid} {
      allow get: if isUser(uid);
    }

    match /orgs/{org} {
      allow get: if isOrgAdmin(org);
    }
  }
}


This might be some sort of scope that I missed in the docs or something else.
